# Facing surefire plugin exception for spring boot application with java 11

Tags: java, spring-boot, ubuntu-20.04, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a spring boot application and whenever I build it, get the following exception.

SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?

This crash happens much before the execution of any test.

Workarounds tried:

1. addition of this configuration below to maven surefire plugin. (This works, but ideally I would want parallel test execution hence this workaround isn't ideal).

```
 <configuration>
      <forkCount>0</forkCount>
    </configuration>
```

2. Change maven version (didn't work)
3. Tried with a different JDK 11. Sdkman provided openjdk in this instance. This also worked. But ideally, I would want the build to be successful even if I use the openjdk-11 installed through sudo apt-get. (ubuntu version 20.04) and not use sdkman at all.

**Any specific reason why this exception would occur only with a very specific environment configuration? What could be the potential causes?**
(openjdk 11 installed through sudo apt-get install, maven 3.8.6, ubuntu 20.04, surefire plugin version 2.22.2).

Comment: why don't you attach the error stack trace. In the configuration / auto-configuration are there any unusual entries?